# SONARCLIPS 3.5.0 Invalid value of sonar.libraries IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Should a new "Invalid value of sonar.libraries / IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching" defect be reported against the SONARCLIPS 3.5.  Or should I try to get defect [SONARCLIPS-430](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCLIPS-430) already fixed in SonarQube Eclipse Plugin 3.5 re-opened?

In Eclipse Mars (4.5.0) when I try to use SonarQube Eclipse Plugin 3.5.0.20150804 to analyze a project, it fails with the error

> Invalid value of sonar.libraries

and the caused by exception

> IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching [...]

According to SONARCLIPS-430, SonarQube Eclipse 3.5 fixed this issue.  But I'm running 3.5 and still encountering the problem.  I'm not using Groovy for this project and SONARCLIPS-430 resulted from the stackoverflow question about groovy and SonarQube Eclipse: [Sonar Eclipse issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764225/sonar-eclipse-issue).

The sonar.libraries involved in this analysis is (copied from sonar-project2243985040659442672.properties):

> sonar.libraries=C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jfr.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar,C:\tool\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/PhysView/PhysViewApi/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Configuration/ConfigurationStructure/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Configuration/ConfigurationStructure/target/test-classes,C:\mvnrepo\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar,C:\mvnrepo\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\osgi\org.osgi.compendium\5.0.0\org.osgi.compendium-5.0.0.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\osgi\org.osgi.core\5.0.0\org.osgi.core-5.0.0.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/DeviceStructure/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/DeviceStructure/target/test-classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.6\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/JavaCommon/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/JavaCommon/target/test-classes,C:\mvnrepo\jython\jython\2.1\jython-2.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.7\commons-codec-1.7.jar,C:\mvnrepo\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.0\commons-cli-1.0.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Logging/Logging/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.5\commons-lang-2.5.jar,C:\mvnrepo\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\easymock\easymock\3.3.1\easymock-3.3.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\cglib\cglib\3.1\cglib-3.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/someProductCommon/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\knopflerfish\bundle\desktop\5.0.1\desktop-5.0.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\somecompany\someproduct\ActionProcessing\7.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT\ActionProcessing-7.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/CircuitManagement/CircuitStructure/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/CircuitManagement/CircuitStructure/target/test-classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/JavaCommon_Bundle/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\hibernate-envers\3.6.4.Final\hibernate-envers-3.6.4.Final.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.6.4.Final\hibernate-core-3.6.4.Final.jar,C:\mvnrepo\antlr\antlr\2.7.6\antlr-2.7.6.jar,C:\mvnrepo\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.6.4.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.4.Final.jar,C:\mvnrepo\cglib\cglib\2.2\cglib-2.2.jar,C:\mvnrepo\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\javassist\javassist\3.12.0.GA\javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\hibernate-tools\3.2.0.ga\hibernate-tools-3.2.0.ga.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\beanshell\bsh\2.0b4\bsh-2.0b4.jar,C:\mvnrepo\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.8\freemarker-2.3.8.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\jtidy\r8-20060801\jtidy-r8-20060801.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/DatabaseCommon/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/LegacyCommunicationsApi/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Automation/automation-common/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/DSLink_bundle/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\iot-dsa\dslink\0.8.0\dslink-0.8.0.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\iot-dsa\logging\0.8.0\logging-0.8.0.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\iot-dsa\runtime_shared\0.8.0\runtime_shared-0.8.0.jar,C:\mvnrepo\io\vertx\vertx-core\2.1.5\vertx-core-2.1.5.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.2.2\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar,C:\mvnrepo\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.21.Final\netty-all-4.0.21.Final.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\beust\jcommander\1.48\jcommander-1.48.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.51\bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/someProductSystem/someProductSystemApi/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/PersistenceService/PersistenceService/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/PersistenceService/PersistenceService/target/test-classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/ServiceManagement/ServiceManagement/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/SecretStuff/SecretStuff/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/SecretStuff/SecretStuff/target/test-classes,C:\mvnrepo\com\somecompany\someproduct\communication\Communication\7.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT\Communication-7.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\jacorb\jacorb\3.1\jacorb-3.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\tanukisoft\wrapper\3.5.4\wrapper-3.5.4.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.1.5\jaxb-impl-2.1.5.jar,C:\mvnrepo\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.1\jaxb-api-2.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\javax\xml\stream\stax-api\1.0-2\stax-api-1.0-2.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.6\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Faults/FaultServiceApi/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Persistence/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\knopflerfish\bundle\remoteserviceadmin-API\1.0.0\remoteserviceadmin-API-1.0.0.jar,C:\mvnrepo\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.4\servlet-api-2.4.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Automation/automation-service/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Automation/automation-service/target/test-classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Configuration/ConfigurationManagement/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\hibernate\hibernate-c3p0\3.6.4.Final\hibernate-c3p0-3.6.4.Final.jar,C:\mvnrepo\c3p0\c3p0\0.9.1\c3p0-0.9.1.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Hibernate/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\postgresql\postgresql\9.2-1003-jdbc4\postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar,C:\mvnrepo\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.12\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-all\2.0.2\groovy-all-2.0.2.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/LegacyCommunications/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/LegacyCommunications/target/test-classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/PanelManager/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/PanelManager/target/test-classes,C:\mvnrepo\org\knopflerfish\bundle\console\4.0.1\console-4.0.1.jar,C:\mvnrepo\org\knopflerfish\log-API\5.0.0\log-API-5.0.0.jar,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Users/UserServiceApi/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/TerminalArbitration/terminalarbitration-common/target/classes,C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/SecretStuffService/target/classes,C:\mvnrepo\com\eclipsesource\jaxrs\publisher\5.0\publisher-5.0.jar,C:\mvnrepo\com\eclipsesource\jaxrs\jersey-all\2.18\jersey-all-2.18.jar

The full exception emitted is

```
    08:57:06.276 ERROR - Invalid value of sonar.libraries for com.somecompany.someproduct.physview:PhysViewImpl
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching 'C:/dev/prodtrunk/someProduct/Configuration/ConfigurationStructure/target/test-classes' in directory C:\dev\prodtrunk\someProduct\PhysView\PhysViewImpl
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.validateDirectories(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:302)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:131)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:114)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.projectBootstrap(ProjectScanContainer.java:114)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:90)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:110)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:185)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Is this folder really existing? C:/dev/mvtrunk/MVServer/Configuration/ConfigurationStructure/target/test-classes

Comment: No, C:/dev/mvtrunk/MVServer/Configuration/ConfigurationStructure/target/test-classes does **NOT** exist.  The nonexistence of this folder may be due to C:/dev/mvtrunk/MVServer/Configuration/ConfigurationStructure/src/test/java existing but being empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julien's comment led to the answer.  For some reason, we had a maven project with an empty src/test/java.  Once, I deleted src/test and src/java, the error went away.

Comment: You can accept your own answer - this is a good practice on Stack Overflow